# Bootstrap 2 columns - right column is squeezed to thin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get a two column layout going, looks good, but it seems like the right column is a bit squeezed.

You can really see it when on an iPad. The right column is a bit slimmer than the left.
How can I get these columns to even out in width?

Here is a link:
https://store-stg.thoracic.org/index2014.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks squeezed because your image in the right hand column is wider than the one on the left (84px on the left, 100px on the right), so the image is holding up more space.  If you resize the images the same, it should even out.